# Como importar a biblioteca HttpClient?

Tags: java, eclipse, biblioteca

Onde devo colocar a *library* `HttpClient`? Em todos os tutoriais é possível encontrar apenas exemplos de códigos, mas ninguém realmente explica que depois de baixar, devemos colocar onde?

http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Existem dois tipos, um com arquivos `httpclient-4.3.6.jar` e outro com arquivos Java, onde coloco os arquivos para em seguida importar, exemplo: `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost`

Comment: Que IDE você está usando? Se não estiver usando nenhuma, o que você faz para (tentar) compilar a aplicação?

Comment: @Victor Estou usando Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que especificar as bibliotecas que você está utilizando no seu `classpath`. Contudo dependendo do tipo de projeto que você está desenvolvendo, existem algumas "convenções".

Por exemplo, se você estiver criando um projeto java web com o eclipse, o local aonde você teria que colocar os JARs, seria em: `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`.

Se você estiver fazendo um projeto 'free-style', você pode verificar como importar a biblioteca nesse link: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Se for um projeto com o [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), você não precisa baixar o JAR, basta adicionar a dependência no `pom.xml` e por aí vai.

Comment: voce poderia botar um exemplo na sua resposta? lembrando que voce [edit] as suas perguntas/respostas sempre que quiser

Comment: Muito obrigada, no mesmo dia que fiz essa pergunta, acabei aprendendo a fazer isso que você mencionou.